# SPJobDefinition Execute Method isn't overriding

Tags: 2007, development, event-handlers, timer-jobs

I built a custom Timer Job on activation I was able to debug it and it was going through Execute method I am overriding but suddenly its not overriding anymore.

Code is here:

```
   public class TimerJob : SPJobDefinition
    {
        private const string TIMERJOB_NAME = "Timer Job";

        public TimerJob()
            : base()
        { 
        }

        public TimerJob(SPWebApplication webApp)
            : base(TIMERJOB_NAME, webApp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        { 
            this.Title = TIMERJOB_NAME; 
        }

        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
            try
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
                getPendingItems();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppCode.Logging.LogWepApplicationErrorMessage(ex, TIMERJOB_NAME, this.WebApplication.Name);
            }
        }
```

While Debugging it goes through second constructor and ignores Execute method and returns control to Feature Receiver class

**Edited**

I defined schedule as below, but even after 5 minutes when I check Job properties > Last run time: it says  N/A

```
    SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
    schedule.EndSecond = 120;
    //SPHourlySchedule schedule = new SPHourlySchedule();
    //schedule.BeginMinute = 0;
    //schedule.EndMinute = 3;
    TimerJob.Schedule = schedule;
    TimerJob.Update();
```

simply doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly calling Execute from within your FeatureReceiver then it should't be called at that time.

The Execute method should be called by the timer service when it's running your timer job

Specifying an EndSecond of 120 isn't valid BeginSecond and EndSecond specify where in the minute it should start and no minutes have more that 60 seconds.

And you don't specify how often it should run by setting Interval.

What you meant was probably:

```
SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.EndSecond = 59;
schedule.Interval = 2;
TimerJob.Schedule = schedule;  
TimerJob.Update();
```

This specifies run every second minute (anywhere in that minute)

And also remember to recycle the TimerJob Service whenever you update your timerjob.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: true, I am not calling it anywhere it should be called automatically :)